# atoi conversion segmentation fault working on windows but not in ubuntu

Tags: c++, vector, atoi

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  

vector <vector<string> > vector2;
vector<string> vector;

for(int i = 0; i < vector.size();i++)
{
    vector2[atoi(vector[i+1].c_str())].push_back(vector[i]);
    i++;
}
```

I try this on Windows, its working fine. But when i try to compile on ubuntu64-bits
it has this segmentation error, anyone enlighten to?

Comment: Seriously **why** would you ever write code like this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you've shown, `vector[i+1].c_str()` will read beyond the end of `vector` for the last iteration of the loop.

Should you exit your loop one iteration sooner?

```
for(int i=0; i<vector.size()-1;i++)
```

If this doesn't help, can you post a fuller example that demonstrates the problem?  It isn't currently possible to say whether e.g. `vector2` has sufficient capacity or `vector`'s contents will always be convertible into suitable indexes.